# Is it possible to split 4 network card ports into 4 different adapters?

Tags: windows, networking, hardware, ethernet

I have a network card which contains 4 Ethernet ports but there is only one network adapter being shown in the adapter settings, I'm looking for a way to somehow split each Ethernet port into it's own adapter, so 1 card with 4 ports and 1 adapter per port.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you're after is the default behaviour of every multi-port NIC - have you installed the latest driver for the NIC? Also show us your device-manager list with the show-hidden-devices checked.

Comment: I've installed the latest drivers for the card already but that didn't really do anything, as for the device manager I don't know if you want a picture of every single category open or just the network adapters, I assume for the sake of time that you only want the network adapters, the broadcom adapter being the 4 port card. http://i.imgur.com/Uuxls47.png

Comment: I think you should have some configuration tool for the network adapter, where you can configure its mode of operation.

Comment: No not that I can see, but if there is a way to do so in Windows or by a 3rd party tool to manage adapters that would be great.

Comment: Such an utility would be provided by the manufacturer of the card.

Comment: Maybe you are asking about something similar to NetSetMan?
http://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but to me that looks like a software that is able to make network adapter profiles for easy IP configuration switching, that's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for software that will split a single network adapter into multiple adapters to each corresponding ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

What I think from your description, you have installed NIC TEAMING Software/Driver, which makes it possible to aggregate all NIC adapters into one networking team with either round-robin load balancing, fault-redundancy and multipath config.
That's perfectly useful if you have redundant and multipath environment there (redundant switches, redundant paths to SAN/NAS ...).
But if you have only plain single path networking, you cannot gain much by using NIC Teaming software.

Take a look at maybe PROGRAMS or maybe under NETWORK ADAPTERS, where for sure you can split them back into 4 separate NIC adapters.

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with most of these terms and concepts, I'm sort of new to it but I'm trying my best to understand, I'm not using any software except for the drivers which were automatically installed and then  I upgraded the drivers but the state remained the same. Also I cannot find an option to split them anywhere, if you could direct me to it that would be great.

Comment: What brand of network card is in question? Broadcom, Intel or something else?

Comment: It's a broadcom netxtreme, I've looked for drivers but it seems there are only manual driver files which I have installed via device manager but there is no software installer for the drivers or some sort of tool which would let me manage it.

Comment: Do you have under NETWTORK ADAPTERS --> RIGHT-CLICK on your network adapter an option "Bridge Connections"? See there if you can un-bridge them, or something like that, depending on drivers.

Comment: Nope, the adapters aren't bridged.